# For a matrix $A$ with an unknown coefficient, how do I show the number of solutions in $Ax=b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Having problem solving the following question:

For what values of $a\in \mathbb{R}$ does $Ax=b$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a+1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & a & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3 \\
    x_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    a \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
have $0, 1, \infty$ solutions?

---

Like it's easy to see that if $a=(-1)$ then row #1 is inconsistent, meaning $0$ solutions; And if $a=1$ then row #2 and #3 are the same, meaning $\infty$ solutions. But how do I show that these are the only values that will give me these number of solutions?

---

I've tried to row reduce the matrix which gives me
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/(a+1) \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & (-1) \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1+a\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
x_1=1/(a+1), \qquad x_2=(-1), \qquad  x_3=1+a, \qquad  x_4=1
$$
Except for $x_1$, I don't see what to do next.

Comment: If $a=0$ your matrix is invertible, and you get a unique solution. More generally, add $-a$ times the second row to the third. The matrix will be upper triangular, and the row operation does not change the determinant. So, the new matrix has the same deteminant as the original. What is the determinant of an upper triangular matrix? What does it tell you about the number of solutions? Don 't forget to eliminate value(s) of $a$ for which the system is inconsistent before you start, which you have done.

Comment: If $rank(A\mid b)=rank(A)=4$, there exists precisely one solution. If $rank(A)<rank(A\mid b)$ there is no solution and if $rank(A)=rank(A\mid b)<4$, there exist infinity many solutions. Can you proceed?

Comment: Following up, notice that the determinant is $1-a^2.$ You can decide inconsistency vs. infinitely many solutions by examining the appropriate values of $a.$  The suggestion by @sampleuser is also spot on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a general result:

> A non-homogeneous linear system $\;A[x]=[b]$  has solutions if and only if the matrix $A$ and the augmented matrix $[Ab]$ have the same rank.
>
> Furthermore, this common rank is the codimension of the set of solutions (which is an affine space).

Proceeding to row reduction, you should obtain there's a unique solution, except if $a=\pm 1$.